# Velocity transformations in special relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, velocity, inertial-frames

[image]

I have a doubt in part (c) of this question.Doesn't relative velocities Vab and Vba need to be just opposite of each other?

Comment: In a single frame the two velocities must be equal and opposite. In two different frames they don't

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.